# Hide past posts in Wordpress with custom field date

Tags: wordpress, hide, custom-fields

I want the blog posts in Wordpress to be sorted by a date set in custom field and hidden when that date has passed.
I got the sorting working but not sure how to proceed further with the hiding of the posts. Date is in 2022-01-01 format in the custom field.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse183601_filter_category_query' );
function wpse183601_filter_category_query( $query ) {
 if( is_front_page() && !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
 
 $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'meta_key'  => 'event_date',
                'value'   => date('Y-m-d'),
                'type'    => 'DATE',
                'compare' => '>='
            )
        );
        
        $query->set( 'orderby','meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key','event_date' );
        $query->set( 'order','ASC' );
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're actually implementing your meta query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `$meta_query` variable to the `meta_query` param. try the below code.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse183601_filter_category_query' );
function wpse183601_filter_category_query( $query ) {
    if( is_front_page() && !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'meta_key' => 'event_date',
                'value'    => date('Y-m-d'),
                'type'     => 'DATE',
                'compare'  => '>='
            )
        );
        
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'event_date' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
```